# Using IBinder in Azure Functions Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to use the IBinder functionality (or what's the best way to mimic it) in azure functions running in typescript or javascript?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-at-runtime).

Azure Function only support imperative binding pattern in C# and other .Net languages. So your idea cannot be realized. You still need to use declarative bindings.